# Swagger UI not rendering the correct response(Should return a JSON response)[This is for the GET request Code 200]

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

Swagger UI is not returning the expected JSON response in the example value. It is returning a empty list.Below are the code snippets I am using,

Gradle Dependency

```
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2')
compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2')
```

**Swagger Config**

```
  @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .ignoredParameterTypes(HttpServletResponse.class)
                    .select()                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.core.controller.v2"))           
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext()))
                    .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
```

**Controller**

```
@ApiOperation(value="A GET request to get a list of all contents for a given user.",
            notes = "This API is used to get the contents for a given user with an NPI and Partner ID",
            response = CoreContentItem.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success response", response = CoreContentItem.class,responseContainer = "List"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request",responseContainer = "String"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error, please contact system administrator")})
```

**Swagger Output**
[Swagger UI for success Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxy43.png)

**Expected JSON response**

This is a sample expected JSON response

```
[
  {
    "item": {
      "id": "3f94ea1a687dda4af3e2",
      "category": null,
      "type": "EXTERNAL",
      "headline": "DO NOT DELETE - REST ASSURED All - HIGH - JV",
      "summary": "DO NOT DELETE - All - HIGH - JV",
      "details": null,
      "mediaURL": "",
      "createdOn": 1493658088000,
      "modifiedOn": 1495553312000,
      "priority": "HIGH",
      "startDate": 1493618400000,
      "endDate": 1588312800000,
      "feedbackEmail": null,
      "totalLikes": 0,
      "totalViews": 2,
      "customData": null,
      "userInteraction": {
        "userLiked": false,
        "userDisliked": false,
        "userViewed": false
      },
      "availableActions": [
        "View",
        "Done",
        "Submit"
      ],
      "externalURL": "https://www.1234.com/vegetables/armando%25e2%2580%2599s-chiles-rellenos/r/5014"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include what your expected response would be in your question.

Comment: Added the JSON response

Comment: Have you tried without specifying it? Also, it looks like your sample is a list of CoreContentItems not just one? If you are actually returning a list, you have to add the ```responseContainer="List"``` param in your @ApiOperation.

Comment: Actually I tried that as well. Still it renders an empty list.

Comment: This json comes from another microservice. Does that make any difference ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Apparently it was a model mapping exception that made the Swagger UI to return an empty list. Now I am able to see the model in example value. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRvp9.png)